# Print tree with indentations

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print out a simple tree that describes a band. I start by creating a node called "Band" and then I make the child "Wind instruments" which in turns have the children "Saxophone" and "Trumpet". Then I make a sibling to "Wind instruments" called "Song" and so on. The code is pretty straightforward:

```
class Node:                                     
    value = ""
    down = None
    right = None
def write(p):
    if p==None:
        return
    print(p.value)
    if p.down!=None:        #My idea is that if we go down the tree, we indent first
        print("    ",end="")     
        write(p.down)
    write(p.right)      #If we don't go down, we simply write out the siblings
a=Node()
a.value="Band"
a.down=Node()
a.down.value="Wind instruments"
a.down.down=Node()
a.down.down.value="Saxophone"
a.down.down.right=Node()
a.down.down.right.value="Trumpet"
a.down.right=Node()
a.down.right.value="Song"
a.down.right.right=Node()
a.down.right.right.value="String instruments"
a.down.right.right.down=Node()
a.down.right.right.down.value="Guitar"
a.down.right.right.down.right=Node()
a.down.right.right.down.right.value="Bass"
write(a)
```

The output is:

```
Band
    Wind instruments
    Saxophone
Trumpet
Song
String instruments
    Guitar
Bass
```

But I want the output to be:

```
Band
    Wind instruments
        Saxophone
        Trumpet
    Song
    String instruments
        Guitar
        Bass
```

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Distinguish between class variables and attributes! After initializing `Node()` `value`, `down` & `right` are class variables being the same for all instances. With assigning a value you added these three as attributes being individual variables of each instance. You can check it by `a = Node(); print(a.__dict__); a.value = 3; print(a.__dict__)`. For trees see e. g. http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch21.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make an indented print depending on the recursion level, the trick is to use an argument keeping the level you're at when recursing:

```
# default with a level of 0, and an indent of 4 characters
def write(p, depth=0, indent=4):
    if p==None:
        return
    # here we multiply the level by the number of indents
    # and then you multiply that number with a space character
    # which will magically show as that number of spaces.
    print("{}{}".format(" "*(indent*depth), p.value))
    if p.down!=None:
        # then you do not need your print(…, end='') hack
        # simply increase the depth
        write(p.down, depth=depth+1, indent=indent)
    # and for siblings, do not increase the depth
    write(p.right, depth=depth, indent=indent)
```

The trick I'm using here is that per default the level is 0, and as you're going deeper, you're increasing the depth by passing the argument increased by 1.

Then, when you want to printout the indentation, all you have to do is multiply the indentation string with that value (and the indent size) so then you get to print the indent as you like:

```
>>> "A"*42
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

So as a result:

```
>>> write(a)
Band
    Wind instruments
        Saxophone
        Trumpet
    Song
    String instruments
        Guitar
        Bass
```

And if you want to make it narrower, because you're having a lot of recursion:

```
>>> write(a, indent=1)
Band
 Wind instruments
  Saxophone
  Trumpet
 Song
 String instruments
  Guitar
  Bass
```

---

as a bonus, I'd advice you to make your `write()` function a method of your `Node` class. And if you rename it `__str__`:

```
class Node:
    value = ""
    down = None
    right = None

    # converts a node into a string
    def as_str(self, depth=0, indent=4):
        # building the current node's line, and add it to a list
        ret = ["{}{}".format(" "*(indent*depth), self.value)]
        if self.down:
            # append down recursion first to the list
            ret.append(self.down.as_str(depth=depth+1, indent=indent))
        if self.right:
            # then append right recursion to the list
            ret.append(self.right.as_str(depth=depth, indent=indent))
        # build the new string, joining each element of the list with a newline
        return "\n".join(ret)

    # a handler for printing the list nicely
    def __str__(self):
        return self.as_str()

    def as_repr(self, depth=0, max_depth=2):
        # building the current node's line, and add it to a list
        ret = ["'{}'".format(self.value)]
        if depth > max_depth:
            ret.append("…")
        else:
            if self.down:
                # append down recursion first to the list
                ret.append(self.down.as_repr(depth=depth+1, max_depth=max_depth))
            if self.right:
                # then append right recursion to the list
                ret.append(self.right.as_repr(depth=depth, max_depth=max_depth))
            # build the new string, joining each element of the list with a newline
        return "Node<{}>".format(",".join(ret))

    # you might want to also make the repr() nicer
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.as_repr()
```

And as a result:

```
>>> a
Node<'Band',Node<'Wind instruments',Node<'Saxophone',…>,Node<'Song',Node<'String instruments',Node<'Guitar',…>>>>>
>>> print(a)
Band
    Wind instruments
        Saxophone
        Trumpet
    Song
    String instruments
        Guitar
        Bass
```

HTH

Comment: I do not recognize this bit:
"{}{}",format(...)
Could you perhaps elaborate on what that does exactly? Otherwise everthing is clear!

Comment: cf [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatstrings) this is the new and preferred way to handle string formatting. The most basic usage, being that for each argument you give to `format()`, it will replace the `{}` tokens in the same order. It would be equivalent to the old style string format: `"%s%s" % (" "*indent*level, p.value)`.

Comment: Wouldn't print(" "*depth * indent,p.value) do the same thing??

Comment: No, because `print("A", "B")` gives `"A B"`, as it adds an extra space between each argument of the `print()` function, so your indent counting would be wrong. Also, using string format helps you build a string, and when you want to build a string to return (cf my second snippet), you can keep the same code.

Comment: Okay then I see why it's needed. Sorry, I'm new to programming, but what is the advantage of having write as a method to Node? Easier to add nodes?

Comment: no, it's easier to *print* nodes, so you can simply do `print(a)` on the 'a' node to print the tree. Same for `repr()` when you want to just analyse the object and not nicely print it out.

Comment: Very nice! As an added bonus, one could have it return a string, which could then be printed, written to a file, etc. Just add an output argument, and then append each line to it.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce an input parameter `i` to control the number of indents to print out.

```
def write(p, i = 1):
    if p==None:
        return
    print(p.value)  
    j = i   # store No. of current indent to j
    if p.down!=None:    # process p.down 
        for ii in range(i):
            print("    ",end="")
        i += 1          # No. of indent + 1
        write(p.down, i)
    if p.right!=None:   # process p.right
        for jj in range(j - 1):
            print("    ",end="")
        write(p.right, j)   #No. of indent keep same
```

running:

```
write(a)
```

results:

```
Band
    Wind instruments
        Saxophone
        Trumpet
    Song
    String instruments
        Guitar
        Bass
```