# How to recursively print my directory structure with indentations? (no imported modules)

Tags: python, recursion, directory, filesystems, directory-structure

So I have created a directory structure from scratch. I am pretty new to python. This is my code

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, name, contents = [], owner = "No owner currently defined"):
        self.name = name
        self.contents = contents
        self.owner = owner
    
    def CreateOwner(self, new_owner):
        self.owner = new_owner


class Directory(File):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Directory({self.name}, {self.contents})"
    

        
            
class PlainFile(File):
    def __init__(self, name, owner = "No owner currently defined"):
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
```

I have made this directory structure

```
root = Directory("root",
                 [PlainFile("boot.exe"), 
                 Directory("home", [
                     Directory("Julius",
                               [PlainFile("dog.jpg"),
                                PlainFile("homework.txt")]), 
                     Directory("Cameron", [PlainFile("Elephant.jpg")])])])
```

And I want to make a function that will recursively print the names of each directory with their subdirectories and files directly underneath them but indented to the right to show that they come from the certain directory. And so each time a new directory is opened from within a directory a new indent is made. I really don't know how to. I have tried for loops and while loops but can't get it to work, I don't even know how to make indentations for opening new directories. Please help :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print tree with indentations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065618/print-tree-with-indentations)

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure. The 'down' and 'right' are kinda confusing me. My directyory structure simply uses a name and then a list so I'm not sure how to relate that answer to my structure. Also, I want to be able to make the function a method of the class and not just a standard function. My code for the structure is just quite different so I am struggling to relate it to mine.

Comment: Can you print the names without indentation?

Comment: @BanAckerman Yes. In that problem, each node had two children, p.down and p.right. They get printed by making two recursive calls: `write(p.down); write(p.right)`. If instead of two children down and right, there had been three children child0, child1, child2, then they would get printed by making 3 recursive calls: `write(p.child0); write(p.child1); write(p.child2)`. In your case, you have a list of children, contents. You want a recursive call for each of them: `write(p.contents[0]); write(p.contents[1]); write(p.contents[2]); ...`

Comment: But since you don't know how many there are, and you don't want to write the same line of code a million times, we use a **loop** instead: `for i in range(len(p.contents)): write(p.contents[i])`; or alternatively `for x in p.contents: write(x)`.

Comment: @BanAckerman If this is confusing for you, I very strongly suggest reading at least that page of the official tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of python and stackoverflow! Good news is that the solution to your problem is very straight-forward. First off, some quick but important comments on your working code:

- `contents`:  should probably only be an attribute of the `Directory` subclass. Also, [mutable default arguments is bad practice](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).
- `CreateOwner`: In python, the convention is to write snake_case instead of CamelCase for everything that isn't class names.
- `owner`: The normal way of implementing a default unset field, even string ones, is usually `None`.

Here's one way to solve your problem: Have a recursive function with 2 parameters: directory and indentation level. After printing the current Directory, check what you are going to do with each `contents` element with [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance). A Directory requires a recursive call with incremented indent, while a PlainFile is simply printed out. Correctly solved, you will get something like this:

[image]

Turning the function into a Directory method is something I'll leave as an exercise to the reader.
Hint:

> One way of doing this is to have 2 seperate methods with the one being used from the outside being a shortcut using the current instance to the main method with the main logic which isn't instance-bound. Bonus points if making the latter a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Try now and see if it goes better. Comment here if you get stuck again. I have coded a solution which works, but trying yourself first is always better for understanding.

Comment: Thank you. I have given it a go, however I am not familiar with isinstance function. I am currently learning python as a University module and I have been advised when making things to avoid built in functions I haven't yet been shown so that I can ensure I really understand what is going on. I was told I can exploit inheritance and define methods that behave different in subclasses, instead of using isinstance. I am struggling very much after trying again with your advice. If you are able to show the solution this will be very helpful to me.

Comment: I will ask to clarify the parts I don't understand for the solution if there are any, as in the next month I will be starting my project of building a game, and I believe that understanding this solution will help me be ready for when I start my project. Thank you for the help so far! I also changed the code of which you said was standard bad practice :) I appreciate these little tips because I feel like such things are left out when being taught at university :)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are comfortable with recursion.   Just some sample code, so that you can build up. For eg I have not used your **repr** overload, you can do that easily.

(On a diff note, In your code , you are inheriting from File for directory/Plain file class , but are not calling parent constructor. Some clean up there, and you can simplify this code too)

```
def rec_print (file_obj:File,level):
    try:
        if file_obj.contents:
            pass
    except Exception as e:
        return

    for obj in file_obj.contents:
        indents = "".join(["\t" for idx in range(level)])
        print( f"{indents }{obj.name}")
        rec_print(obj, level+1)
```